# How to run gittutorial?

Tags: git, manpage

From the git man page:

"See **gittutorial**(7) to get started, then see **giteveryday**(7) for a useful minimum set of commands. The **Git User’s Manual**[1] has a more in-depth introduction."

I am however, unable to find a command called gittutorial. How do I access it?

Comment: gittutorial is not git command

Comment: manual pages for commands are in section 1 and 8, so it would be *gittutorial(1)* if it were a command. A page in section 7 is miscellaneous documentation. See `man 1 man` for more about the manual. `man 7 man-pages` is also interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git help tutorial` or `man 7 gittutorial`.  The `(7)` in parentheses is a manpage section, section 7 is for introductory/expository conceptual discussion, `man 7 intro` gets you the section 7 intro page. Git help displays the docs in whatever form they're installed, by default that's manpages but you can say e.g. `git help --web tutorial` to see whether you've got the html docs installed too.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial. You could run `git help gittutorial` to browse the local manual. On Windows, the local manual pages are in `mingw64/share/doc/git-doc/` under Git's installation path, which you could also manually open and read.

For `giteveryday`, you could run `git help giteveryday`.

But for `Git User's Manual`, it's https://www.git-scm.com/docs/user-manual. `git help user-manual` raises an error saying the system cannot find the page `gituser-manual.html`, which should actually be `user-manual.html`. It seems `git help` automatically inserts `git` at the beginning. So `git help everyday` and `git help tutorial` also work, but `git help user-manual` fails.

Comment: There's links in the html docs, `git help --web`, the description there links to everyday, tutorial, user-manual, they work for me.